# How to evaluate js values using < > operators from wasm?

Tags: go, webassembly

Go has an [equal](https://golang.org/pkg/syscall/js/#Value.Equal) method to test equality between JS values. How can we use greater (or less) operators to evaluate js values ?  Do I need to write a javascript function  in js(i.e. `function GT(a, b, op){return eval(a, op, b)}`) just for that?

```
var a, b js.Value 

// test if a > b or b > a
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Value.Equal](https://golang.org/pkg/syscall/js/#Value.Equal) method is meant to test whether two [js.Value](https://golang.org/pkg/syscall/js/#Value) objects are equal (same as the javascript `===` operator).

It **is not** restricted to number types.

Instead, to perform comparison you need to obtain typed variables and compare them. Given ints, you can use the following:

```golang
var a, b js.Value
// Get them from somewhere.

aint, bint := a.Int(), b.Int()

if a > b { ... }
```

Do check the documentation for [Value.Int()](https://golang.org/pkg/syscall/js/#Value.Int) and others, they will panic if the conversion is not possible. Use [Value.Type()](https://golang.org/pkg/syscall/js/#Value.Type) first to make sure you have the expected type.

Comment: I figured that would be the case. Type switching then unboxing and executing the op in Go(wasm) seems a bit laborious(api wise) and wasteful(perf wise)